# Error with sending an arrays and an object in a GET API and getting them in the reducer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm working on a project where I need to send an arrays and an object from the backend (nodejs) through a GET api to the frontend (reactjs) and have both of those be accessible in my reducer. I have never done this, and I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way. I am currently getting an error saying that `totalPages` from this line: `export const orderMineListReducer = (state = {orders:[], totalPages}, action) => {` is not defined. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to go about sending a GET api with an arrays and an object and receiving an arrays and an object in the reducer. Thank you!

Below, I have included what I have tried to do so far:

Backend:
orderRouter.js

```
orderRouter.get(
    '/mine',
    isAuth,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
        const page = req.query.page || 1;
        const perPage = 20
        const orders = await Order.find({ user: req.user._id }).skip(page * perPage).limit(perPage);
        const total = await Order.countDocuments();

        const totalPages = Math.ceil(total / perPage).toString();
        res.status(200).send({
            data: 
                [orders], 
                totalPages,
            });
    }),
);
```

Frontend

orderReducer.js

```
 export const orderMineListReducer = (state = {orders:[], totalPages}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ORDER_MINE_LIST_REQUEST:
        return { ...state, loading: true };
      case ORDER_MINE_LIST_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, loading: false, orders: action.payload.orders, totalPages: action.payload.totalPages,};
      case ORDER_MINE_LIST_FAIL:
        return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

orderActions.js

```
export const listOrderMine = (page) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_MINE_LIST_REQUEST });
    const {
        userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
        const { data } = await Axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/orders/mine?page=${page}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
            },
           
        });
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_MINE_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        const message = error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message;
        dispatch({ type: ORDER_MINE_LIST_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
};
```

I've also tried just having

```
res.status(200).send({
                orders, 
                totalPages,
        });
```

instead of `res.status(200).send({data: { orders, totalPages,}});`

with my reducer like so:

```
  export const orderMineListReducer = (state = { data: {} }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ORDER_MINE_LIST_REQUEST:
        return { ...state, loading: true };
      case ORDER_MINE_LIST_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, loading: false, data: action.payload,};
      case ORDER_MINE_LIST_FAIL:
        return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

however in  my `OrderHistoryScreen.js` where I have

```
const orderMineList = useSelector((state) => state.orderMineList); 
 const { loading, data, error,} = orderMineList;
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => { dispatch(listOrderMine());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

I am getting `undefined` for `console.log(data.orders)` and empty `{}` for `console.log(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your response has this scheme:

```
{
  data: {
    orders,
    totalPages
  }
}
```

Axios.get will resolve to an object with this schema:

```
{
  data: {
    data: {
      orders,
      totalPages
    }
  },
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  ...
}
```

So you need to change the destructuring or dispatch `data.data` like this:
`dispatch({ type: ORDER_MINE_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data.data });`

Check the Axios documentation on the response schema: https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

Comment: Oh, okay, I didn't realize it would give me the two datas. I'm still having an issue though. Above I've included what else I have tried. Do you have any idea why I might not be getting my array and object?